# OpenID login page throws error

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, internet-explorer

From today morning I can't login to Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. It throws an error.

Also, the login page doesn't show any OpenID providers.

I am using IE 8. I have tested this also with IE 7, the same problem exist everywhere.

**PS:** I can login to meta because I have enabled remember my login while login to meta sometime before. So it automatically allows me in.

I have a question, Since all the Stack Overflow sites share common logins, why don't you automatically allow me to login to other sites if I already entered in one site (something like Gmail & orkut).

Comment: They may share login info, but they do not share the same domain. And you have cleared your cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, extra comma in the openid javascript file -- my bad. Sorry about that. Fixed!

Oddly, only IE was perturbed by this extra comma.

Comment: It'll be odd if IE ain't odd. In any case, good that the problem is resolved :)

Comment: thanks Jeff, its working fine now.. :)